# Clearing and freeing memory

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, c#-2.0

I am developing a windows application using C# .Net. This is in fact a plug-in which is installed in to a DBMS. The purpose of this plug-in is to read all the records (a record is an object) in DBMS, matching the provided criteria and transfer them across to my local file system as XML files. My problem is related to usage of memory. Everything is working fine. But, each time I read a record, it occupies the memory and after a certain limit the plug in stops working, because of out of memory.

I am dealing with around 10k-20k of records (objects). Is there any memory related methods in C# to clear the memory of each record as soon as they are written to the XML file. I tried all the basic memory handling methods like clear(), flush(), gc(), & finalize()/ But no use.

Please consider he following:

- Record is an object, I cannot change this & use other efficient data
  structures.
- Each time I read a record I write them to XML. and repeat    this
  again & again.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a garbage collected language. Therefore, to reclaim memory used by an object, you need to make sure all references to that object are removed so that it is eligible for collection. Specifically, this means you should remove the objects from any data structures that are holding references to them after you're done doing whatever you need to do with them.

If you get a little more specific about what type of data structures you're using we can probably give a more specific answer.